# Library resources get removed from folder and renamed on release

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, proguard

I am building an application with Flutter. I implemented an SDK in the android app side. I have no problem with the SDK in a debug APK but when I release, the resources that are needed for the SDK are removed from their containing folder and renamed. For instance: `app-debug.apk > res > raw > success.mp3` becomes `app-release.apk > res > w3.mp3`

I assume that this has to do with proguard but adding `-dontshrink -dontobfuscate -dontoptimize` to the proguard file didn't change anything. I've even tried `-keep class com.SDK.** { *; }` hoping that this would keep all the resources as well as the classes but to no avail. In the app level build.gradle in the release build type I have also implemented `minifyEnabled false` as well as `shrinkResources false` but these also did not resolve the issue.

Is there something I am missing about Flutter, Gradle, or even both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a rookie mistake. It had nothing to do with proguard or gradle. The issue came in when I had refactored the package name through File => Project Structure. It refactored everything except the release AndroidManifest so the app was trying to pull the resources from the wrong place on a release.